# Infinite Group with Specific Property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite group such that every non identity element of $G$ is of order $2$. Does it follow that $G$ has to be uncountable?

I feel this is true,but not able to prove it rigorously. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think it only means that each element is it's own inverse as $a^2=e$ for all $a \in G$, then $a = a^{-1}$ must hold. But I really am kind of a beginner in algebra.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Any infinite group has a countably infinite subgroup (just take subgroup generated by any countable subset), and any subgroup of a group with your property also has that property, so the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be the group consisting of those sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $0$'s and $1$'s in which only finitely many $1$'s occur.  This set, with the operation of componentwise addition modulo $2$, is a countably infinite group in which all elements except the identity have order $2$.

Comment: This is isomorphic to the direct sum mentioned by Matt Samuel in his second comment on learnmore's incorrect answer.  But I'll leave my answer here for the benefit of anyone who isn't familiar with direct sums.